# How to iterate over the rows of a table with p5js using table.setNum()

Tags: javascript, csv, export-to-csv, p5.js

```
function saveAsCSV() {
  
  let simulationOutput = new p5.Table();

  let newRow = simulationOutput.addRow();
  
  simulationOutput.addColumn("Total Population");
  simulationOutput.addColumn("Human Population");
  simulationOutput.addColumn("Predator Population");
  simulationOutput.addColumn("Prey Population");
  simulationOutput.addColumn("Food Population");

  for(var i = 1; i<totalDynamic.length; i++){
    simulationOutput.addRow().setNum("Total Population", int(totalDynamic[i]));
  }
  
  for(let j = 1; j<predDynamic.length; j++){
    simulationOutput.setNum(j,1, int(predDynamic[j]));
    j++;
  }
  
  save(simulationOutput, month()+"/"+day()+"_T:"+hour()+":"+minute()+":"+second()+"_Simulation_Output.csv");
}
```

I'm looking to save the outputs of a simulation to a .csv file, but I can't seem to iterate over the rows of the table using the for loop. I'm using p5.js

```
for(let j = 1; j<predDynamic.length; j++){
    simulationOutput.setNum(j,1, int(predDynamic[j]));
    j++;}
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setNum')
    at o.default.Table.setNum (p5.min.js:3:593463)
    at o.default.Element.saveAsCSV (predator_prey.js:255:22)
    at o.default.Element.<anonymous> (p5.min.js:3:429692)
```

The problem is with iterating using the j, but I can't see how this returns undefined?

Comment: This works for me with p5.js 1.4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because `totalDynamic.length` < `predDynamic.length`

A row is added for each item in `totalDynamic` and not `predDynamic`. But when there are **more** items in `predDynamic` than `totalDynamic`, The `p5.Table()` doesn't recognize the rows because they haven't been initialized yet. Possible solution:

```
for(let j = 1; j<predDynamic.length; j++){
   if(simulationOutput.rows.length <= j) simulationOutput.addRow();
   simulationOutput.setNum(j,1, int(predDynamic[j]));
   j++;
}
```